# Access-list won't show all hit matches

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, acl, logging, access-control

I have access-lists in place. When i use the `show ip access-list` command, some of access-lists show counters (hit counts), and some don't. If I change the rule from permit to deny, interesting traffic is denied and counters will appear, but when I change to permit again the counters won't increase, although there is the traffic which is allowed with same sequence number.

Comment: if it does not have a hit, it would indicate that there is no matching traffic, however, without seeing the ACL and the IP/Source that is passing i could only guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the platform is Cisco Catalyst as reflected in the tags for the question, that may be the case. Some platforms reflect only punted (soft-switched) packets in the "show ip access-list [...]" output, while others reflect none. For example, for Catalyst 6500 and Sup720 You'd need to use `show tcam int x/y acl in|out protocol`, while for other Catalyst platforms You'd usually be able to see aggregated statistics for ASIC or whole box via `show access-list hardware counters`.